# Building sucessive union of lists/arrays using comprehension and iteration

Tags: list, python-3.x, set, iteration

Afternoon-I'm currently trying to read up on/implement more clever ways to form the union of sub lists after imposing varying conditions on the original list (or, more generally, any list)-specifically the successive union over what may be a large number of sublists.  the data within may be strings, or numerical data.

For example, I could form sub lists of the following list based on the condition if 'a' appears in the ith position of the list.

```
mylist = [a b c d
          d a b c
          c b a d
          b d c a]

mysublist1 = [item for item in mylist if item[0] == a]

mysublist = [ a b c d]
```

In this example, I could repeat this process and change the condition to be the ith position of the list and generate 4 sublists. I could then-for demonstrations sake, reform the original list using the handy set functions

```
set(thisset).union(thatset)
```

However, without being clever this will take n-1 instances of these guys (forming the first union, then taking successive unions)-which can get dicey.

Is anyone aware of any methods that would make this a bit more elegant?  I have tried  appending sets to a list and then defining the successive union over the size of this list be fruitful (but I'm getting some type errors!)

Thanks!